# Función que devuelva numero invertido

Tags: c

de esta forma invierte el primero y el ultimo. lo quise pasar a función.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    char num[3];
    scanf("%s",&num);
    putchar(num[3]); putchar(num[1]); putchar(num[2]); putchar(num[0]);
}
```

así quedó y no logro hacer que funcione. (debe tomar 4 numeros e invertir el primero el ultimo.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void orden_numeros(char num){
    putchar(num[3]); putchar(num[1]); putchar(num[2]); putchar(num[0]);
}

int main(){
    char num[3];
    scanf("%s",&num);
    orden_numeros(num);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en que tu función orden_numeros la cual recibe como parámetro un char, y debería ser una rreglo de char o un puntero a char para que puedas trabajar con sus índices como hicistes en el main.

Puedes cambiarla de una de las siguientes maneras. Funcionan!!!

```
void orden_numeros(char* num){
    putchar(num[3]);
    putchar(num[1]);
    putchar(num[2]);
    putchar(num[0]);
}

void orden_numeros(char num[3]){
    putchar(num[3]);
    putchar(num[1]);
    putchar(num[2]);
    putchar(num[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te cuento que estas tratando de invertir es una cadena de char o letras, para invertir un numero, necesitas una variable de tipo **int**, y un ciclo para dividir ese numero entre 10 hasta que la variable llegue ser un solo numero.

mira este ejemplo: http://sos-programacion.blogspot.com/2011/04/como-invertir-numeros-en-c.html